# Water-damaged phone no longer shows battery status or recognizes my SIM card

Tags: installation, t-mobile-g2x

I have a T-Mobile G2X, and I accidently poored a glass of water on it. It turns on, wifi works and all the apps are the fine. However, the battery status is displayed as a little question mark, the date was reset to 2007 and it wont read my SIM card.

How can I do a clean install of Android? I'd like to see if that solves my problem, but I'm not sure exactly how to do that.

Is there anything else that could fix these issues?

Answer (score 2):

[Perform a factory reset](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19863/how-to-reinstall-android-to-the-fresh-stock). But I doubt that this will fix your problems. Sounds like they are caused by hardware.

Comment: I did a factory reset already and I have the same issue. I think the water caused a shortcut and affected the software. if it was hardware related I dont think the phone would turn on and wifi is working etc etc